# How to execute Cypher in a file?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on windows. I have created a text file of Cypher query using notepad. How can I run the query in the file using Neo4jShell or Neo4j web interface console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add `-file` as a parameter when starting the console.

On windows, it would look like this :

```
Neo4jShell.bat -file path/to/cql/file
```

Or you could also print the result into a new file

```
Neo4jShell.bat -file path/to/cql/file > path/to/output/file
```

I'm also sure there is a way to do it from within the shell and not at startup, as it was once demonstrated to me by Stefan Armbruster but for the love of god, I can't remember how he did it. But this approach works as well.

Answer (score 17):

On Debian/Ubuntu or any **nix* installations, use the following from terminal:

$ `neo4j-shell -c <  path-to-cypher-query-file.cql`

Note that each cypher query in the file must end in a semicolon and must be separated by a blank line from the other query. Also, the `.cql` ending (file format) is not mandatory.

Comment: currently when one runs this, it also attempts to run commented out code. is there a better way to avoid this. doesn't matter too much, just curious

Answer (score 7):

```
$ neo4j-shell -file query.cql
```

or using `cypher-shell`

```
$ cat query.cql | cypher-shell
```

Answer (score 4):

The neo4jShell.bat file has been removed since this question was asked. The new approach to execute cypher files is to use the web application called [LazyWebCypher](http://www.lyonwj.com/LazyWebCypher/) .

Comment: `neo4j-shell.bat` still exists, [you just need to download the zip file to get it](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/using-neo4j-shell-neo4j-ce-3x/). It is deprecated though, but the official replacement is `cypher-shell`.

Answer (score 2):

With Neo4j web interface I just do copy&paste.

On the console I sometimes use curl to talk to Neo4j's REST interface. That allows me to use the same queries (with references to separate parameters) that I have in my application.
You have to wrap the query in your file into a json object for that.

data.json:

```
{
  "query":"match (u:User) where u.username={username} return u",
  "params":{"username":"trenkerbe"}
}
```

command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @data.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
```

Answer (score 0):

./bin/neo4j-shell -path ../data/databases/ -c < commands.cql

on Neo4j    3.2.1

Comment: You no longer need the `-c` on latest versions.