# Automate creation of relationships between unconnected nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-cql

I have a text file of 178000 relationships in this format.

> File starts here...

MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:483}), (h:PERSON{userid:1086})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h)

with 1 as dummy

MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:1086}), (h:PERSON{userid:483})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h)

with 1 as dummy

MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:483}), (h:PERSON{userid:1095})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h)

with 1 as dummy

MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:1095}), (h:PERSON{userid:483})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h)

with 1 as dummy.

> File ends here

I have the nodes created in Neo4j. I do not want to manually copy paste each and every query in the browser,

Is there a way to automate this problem?

Answer (score 3):

`neo4j-shell -c <  yourfile.cql` will run the cypher queries in the file, though I would split that query up into smaller ones by replacing the `with 1 as dummy` with semicolons.

Maybe a duplicate of [How to execute Cypher in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462306/how-to-execute-cypher-in-a-file)

Comment: Is the browser "http://localhost:7474/browser/" the shell in itself? If not how can I start the shell?

Comment: You run that command in your terminal, assuming you're in *nix. If you're in Windows see the link.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a list of Cypher queries generated from tabular data, like a CSV file.

You could have a look at [`LOAD CSV`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher), which would allow you to write a single, generic statement, and also commit periodically, to avoid that huge transaction which could lead to an OutOfMemoryError server-side.

More generally, from your other questions, it looks like you should read a bit more of the Neo4j documentation, not necessarily as a whole, but at least skim through the table of content to see what it's capable of.

Comment: I am looking through the documentation and asking questions where I am getting stuck. I feel there is a lack of tutorials.

Comment: Maybe search for "neo4j data import"? I get lots of links to the appropriate pages in the documentation, as well as blog articles, with that. Anyway, have a look at `LOAD CSV`...