# neo4j - BULK CREATE statement

Tags: neo4j, insert

I am importing the GOT data into neo4j.
https://github.com/neo4j-examples/game-of-thrones

these are json files.
Initially I converted to CSv and tried the LOAD CSV apoc funstion. but couldn get it to work.

I then converted the files to CREATE statements. I have to run them line by line.

Is there away to run the whole batch of CREATE statements?

cheers
Ian

Comment: Have you tried the `cypher-shell` command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462306/how-to-execute-cypher-in-a-file). Hope this is the answer you are looking for.